# How to attach an audio file into library?

Tags: java

I am developing an application with Android/Java. I need to attach a list of audio files into my java library. So that the developer can use the library and play the audio files. How can I attach the audio files into my Java library and how to call them as file path to play them?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an `Android` Library, you can put your audio file in the `raw` folder. People using your library can refer to it using `com.example.yourlibrary.R.raw.sample_audio_file`.

I hope this is what you were looking for. The file will be embedded when the library is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific audioFiles then add them to the special resource folder and refer to them as `getResourceAsStream` . If you want user to use their own files - provide the variable for the folder path and make a filter to use only specific files, i.e *.mp3.

If they are stored in specific resources folder, why not to create special `Accessor` class for the developers to use it? Like you will have a `*.jar` file that will contain files in the separate resource folder with the `Accessor` to work with them.